# Find parameters of Tensorflow graph

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xKI0SIrXB6Wl8SBuX-D1otI_8nuHjza1/view) TensorFlow graph. I successfully obtained input_arrays and output_arrays of this graph using this script:

```
import tensorflow as tf
gf = tf.GraphDef()   
m_file = open('deeplabv3_mnv2_pascal_tain.pb','rb')
gf.ParseFromString(m_file.read())

for n in gf.node:
    print( n.name )
```

I am stuck at a point where I cannot obtain:

```
input_shapes
```

from the same graph. How do I get this information provided I only have [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xKI0SIrXB6Wl8SBuX-D1otI_8nuHjza1/view) graph.

Comment: If you are down voting please let me know the reason. I can change my question accordingly. If I still didn't change the question after giving reason then feel free to down vote.

Comment: Your Google drive needs permission. Please try to include that information here if possible. I didn't downvote.

Comment: Ive updated the permissions please try now

Comment: By input_shapes do you mean the shape of the input (which you already get the name) ?

Comment: --input_shapes=1,1568,1176,3, means the dimensions of training set. Ive changed them according to my training set